# caddr in Clojure

Tags: clojure, lisp, jvm

What is the equivalent of Lisp's caddr in Clojure?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

caddr in Lisps is often used in a manner that amounts to destructuring. Clojure has ubiquitous support for destructuring, so caddr is less useful.

```
  (let [[_ _ x] [1 2 3 4]]
    x) ;; -> 3
```

EDIT: In response to @4bu3li.

```
(defn describe-path [[first :as edge]] 
  `(there is a ~(last edge) going ~first from here.))
```

There is no way to specify the last element w/ destructuring, but that's not really related to the original question anyway.

Comment: @Hamish Grubijian: Well, any seq with at least as many elements as you have in the binding list. If the sequence were instead `[1 2]`, then `x` would be nil since there is no third item.

Comment: @dnolan Would destructing work with this function?    (defn describe-path [edge]
  `(there is a ~(last edge) going ~(first edge) from here.))

Answer (score 18):

As `caddr` is equivalent to [`third`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_firstc.htm) in Common Lisp, the closest I see in Clojure is [`nth`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/nth):

```
(nth collection 2)
```

It's more generic than `caddr`, in that it aspires to work on more structures that cons cell chains. Note, though, that's it's not a [*place*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_p.htm#place) as it is in Common Lisp.

Comment: I think you mean `(nth collection 2)` — the `first`, `second`, etc. functions start at 1, but `nth` starts at 0.

Answer (score 8):

Usually when I need to map a concept from one language to another, I check http://hyperpolyglot.org/

Clojure is included on the Lisp page: http://hyperpolyglot.org/lisp

From this, it appears that there is no direct analogue to caddr.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose the closest equivalent of `(caddr foo)` is `(first (nnext foo))`. But Clojure doesn't exactly have the "everything is a list" religion that most Lisps have and lacks the heavy list-traversal shortcuts from Common Lisp in favor of a shared interface for sequences.

Answer (score 4):

It's not that hard to compose and make your own ca+d+r functions

```
(defn make-cadr
  [fn-name]
  (let [cadr {\a first \d rest}]
    (apply comp (map cadr (butlast (drop 1 fn-name))))))

((make-cadr "caddr") [1 2 3 4 5])
```

Comment: +1 for compiling the function name, first time I've seen that technique :-)

Answer (score 3):

There's no *direct* equivalent to `caddr` in Clojure, because Clojure deals with sequences instead of concrete `cons` cells. Worthwhile reading is the [Clojure documentation on sequences](http://clojure.org/sequences).

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in such way:

```
(defn caddr [list]
  (first (rest (rest list))))
```

Answer (score 1):

A slight variation on Sathish's answer, but using a macro that compiles the `cadr` functions:

```
(defmacro cadr-compiler [name]
  (let [cadr {\a first \d rest}]
    `(defn ~name [l#]
       ((apply comp (map ~cadr (butlast (drop 1 ~(str name))))) l#))))

(cadr-compiler caddr)
(caddr [1 2 3 4 5])  ;=> 3
```